# React Router Dom: <Route/> did not work properly

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router-dom

I am trying to build a chat app. when i using react-router-dom, I got some problem in .

Here index.js file:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Here is my App.js File:

```
import { Route, Switch, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import HomePage from "./Components/HomePage/HomePage";
import ChatPage from "./Components/ChatPage/ChatPage";

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <>
        <Route path="/" components={HomePage} />
        <Route path="/chats" component={ChatPage} />
      </>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And HomePage.js file:

```
import React from "react";

const HomePage = () => {
  return <div>HomePage ............</div>;
};

export default HomePage;
```

And ChatPage.js file:

```
import React from "react";

const ChatPage = () => {
  return <div>ChatPages.............. </div>;
};

export default ChatPage;
```

But the "http://localhost:3000/chats" give me the output. The other route did not work. Blank page was shown. **"react-router-dom" version: "^5.3.3".**

[image]
[image]

Where is the problem? How can I solve this? Thank You.

Comment: Typo, there is no `components` prop on the `Route` component. `<Route path="/" components={HomePage} />` should be `<Route path="/" component={HomePage} />`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are using v5 you need to use `switch`, I see you importe it but you don't use it:

App.js

```
import { Route, Switch, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import HomePage from "./Components/HomePage/HomePage";
import ChatPage from "./Components/ChatPage/ChatPage";

    function App() {
      return (
        <div>
          <> /*You can remove this fragments too*/
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
              <Route path="/chats" component={ChatPage} />
            </Switch>
          </>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

and in index.js you can remove `Routes` from this line:

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
```

also change that line: you have **components** in plural it must be in singular **component**

`<Route path="/chats" components={ChatPage} />`

to

`<Route path="/chats" component={ChatPage} />`

Comment: I tried with switch also. that's why it was imported. But did not work for me.

Comment: when i used switch, all routes shown blank page.

Comment: Everything seems fine, why you do not update to react router v6, it is almost the same. If not maybe the  <React.StrictMode>?

Comment: Hey! I found it, check the updated answer